# how do I get a groovy MockFor/StubFor ignore method to use a demand method

Tags: unit-testing, testing, groovy, mocking

Below is the behavior I am seeking. I want a Groovy [MockFor ignore method](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/mock/interceptor/MockFor.html#ignore%28java.lang.Object,%20groovy.lang.Closure%29) to call a demand method, instead of the ignore method calling the `dontIgnoreMe()` method directly.

Essentially, I want to replace `dontIgnoreMe()` me with a mock, and have `ignoreMe()` call the mock (which I have done with metaClass)  It appears like categories might be a better solution. I'll look into that next week, see: [groovy nabble feed](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/metaclass-how-to-replace-and-restore-a-method-tt5042834.html#none)

```
import groovy.mock.interceptor.MockFor

class Ignorable {
    def dontIgnoreMe() { 'baz' }
    def ignoreMe() { dontIgnoreMe() }
}

def mock = new MockFor(Ignorable)
mock.ignore('ignoreMe')
mock.demand.dontIgnoreMe { 'hey' }

mock.use {
    def p = new Ignorable()
    assert p.dontIgnoreMe() == 'hey'
    assert p.ignoreMe() == 'hey'
}
```

---

```
Assertion failed: 

assert p.ignoreMe() == 'hey'
       | |          |
       | baz        false
       Ignorable@6879c0f4
```

Answer (score 1):

For groovy developers I strongly recommend Spock Framework!

Use [Spy](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.0/interaction_based_testing.html) like in the code below:

```
def "Testing spy on real object with spock"() {
    given:
    Ignorable ignorable = Spy(Ignorable)
    when:
    ignorable.dontIgnoreMe() >> { 'hey' }
    then:
    ignorable.ignoreMe() == 'hey'
    ignorable.dontIgnoreMe() == 'hey'
}
```